# Move collectionView on button click (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView` that I am using to display my onboarding screen. Each cell takes the full width and height of the view and currently I have it working fine swiping between each cell (page).

I have to implement a next button. This button will just move the collectionView over 1 index on each click (till the end). I am just trying to make it move right now and even though there a few similar questions I have not been able to come up with a solution this far.

This is what I have tried:

```swift
@IBAction func nextPageButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let visibleItems: NSArray = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems as NSArray
    let currentItem: NSIndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! NSIndexPath
    let nextItem: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: currentItem + 1, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextItem as IndexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

I get an error about performing the binary operator on line 4 (currentItem + 1) but even if I hard code the number and try and run it, I still dont get the scroll to function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to increment an indexPath, you must increment the indexPath's row.

```
let nextItem = NSIndexPath(row: currentItem.row + 1, section: 0)
```

*Example*

```
@IBAction func nextPageButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first.flatMap({
        IndexPath(item: $0.row + 1, section: $0.section)
    }), collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) != nil else {
        return
    }

    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks mate!

Comment: It didn't work still need to click more than once to move

Comment: not working, I am trying to achieve something on a horizontal scrolling collectionView, that scrolls to its next index on click of the next button.

Answer (score 21):

**Try these methods for left as well as right  increment of your collection cell**

> For right increment

```
@IBAction func Btn_RightAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    let visibleItems: NSArray = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems as NSArray
    let currentItem: IndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! IndexPath
    let nextItem: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem.item + 1, section: 0)
           if nextItem.row < ImgArr.count {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextItem, at: .left, animated: true)

    }
}
```

> For left increment

```
@IBAction func Btn_LeftAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    let visibleItems: NSArray = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems as NSArray
    let currentItem: IndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! IndexPath
    let nextItem: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem.item - 1, section: 0)
    if nextItem.row < ImgArr.count && nextItem.row >= 0{
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextItem, at: .right, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@IBAction func showNextItemCollectionViewOnClick(_ sender: Any) {

        let visibleItems: NSArray = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems as NSArray

        var minItem: NSIndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! NSIndexPath
        for itr in visibleItems {

            if minItem.row > (itr as AnyObject).row {
                minItem = itr as! NSIndexPath
            }
        }

        let nextItem = NSIndexPath(row: minItem.row + 1, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextItem as IndexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
    }
```

Steps:

1. Find all visible items in "visibleItems" variable
2. Find min item present in the visible items
3. Go to nextItem
4. scroll to required item.

Note: this works even in case when more than one items are present in collection view & on button click we want "one" more item to be visible if we want movement of more than one item change "1" to required value.

Answer (score 3):

An issue with collectionView.scrollToItem function on ios 14. So You can try this

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func scrollToNextItem() {
        let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.contentOffset.x + self.bounds.size.width))
        self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
    }
    func moveToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {
            self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: contentOffset, y: self.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
        }
}
```

and this is your button action

```
@IBAction func nextButtonAct(_ sender: Any) {
   collectionView.scrollToNextItem()
}
```

Comment: This just saved me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> For me using in ios 14, above solution didn't work properly.  So here
> is the solution.

```
extension UICollectionView {

 func scrollToNextItem() {
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.contentOffset.x + 
    self.bounds.size.width))
    self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
}

func scrollToPreviousItem() {
    let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.contentOffset.x - self.bounds.size.width))
    self.moveToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)
}

func moveToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {
    self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: contentOffset, y: self.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
}}
```

Usage:

```
func rightButtonTapped() {
    infoCollectionView.scrollToNextItem()
}

func leftButtonTapped() {
    infoCollectionView.scrollToPreviousItem()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for **didTapBack** you just need the current page but in **didTapForward** you need also to check **currentPage** if it does not arrive at last index of **yourArray**

> ```
> if currentPage > self.yourArray.count - 2 {
>     return
> }
> ```

to be sure that you didn't arrive to the last index

> ```
> @IBAction func didTapBack(_ sender: Any) {
>
>     let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage - 1, section: 0)
>     collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
> }
>
> @IBAction func didTapForward(_ sender: Any) {
>
>     if currentPage > self.yourArray.count - 2 {
>         return
>     }
>
>     let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage + 1, section: 0)
>     collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for scroll collection view on button click.

**Note:** sender.tag is used to handle left and right scrolling.

```
let visibleItems = collecitonView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted { $0 < $1 }

guard let indexPath = sender.tag == 0 ? visibleItems.first : visibleItems.last else {
            return
        }
        
let nextItem: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag == 0  ? indexPath.item - 1 : indexPath.item + 1, section: 0)
        
if nextItem.row < 10 && nextItem.row >= 0{
            
            collecitonView.scrollToItem(at: nextItem, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
```